# sublimelinter: problems with csslinter

Tags: css, node.js, sublimetext

I have installed sublime text 2 in mac os x mountain lion (10.8), and the plugin sublime linter. For css verification, the plugin needs node.js.

When I start sublime text, the console show this:

```
ValueError: Error from csslint: /Users/carloslopez/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/SublimeLinter/sublimelinter/modules/libs/csslint/linter.js:23
    var report = CSSLint.verify(code, ruleset);
                         ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'verify' of undefined
    at Object.exports.lint (/Users/carloslopez/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/SublimeLinter/sublimelinter/modules/libs/csslint/linter.js:23:26)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/carloslopez/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/SublimeLinter/sublimelinter/modules/libs/jsengines/node.js:31:31)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:85:17)
    at Pipe.onread (net.js:424:51)
```

How it can be resolved? Thanks!

Comment: This question belongs on sublimelinter's issues page: https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bundled csslint-node.js is broken.
Use as a workaround the csslint-node.js provided by npm for node.js

https://registry.npmjs.org/csslint/-/csslint-0.9.8.tgz